# Create BMP file of given size in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, bitmap, python-3.5, python-imaging-library

I am currently trying to create a BMP file in Python of given exact size. I need this size with an accuracy down to a byte, and I'm having problems generating an image. To do this I'm using Pillow library as follows:

```
img = Image.new('RGB', (1, size//4), "black")
pixels = img.load()

for i in range(img.size[0]):
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        pixels[i,j] = (i, j, 1)

img.save("image.bmp")
```

Where `size` is equal to `1*1024*1024 = 1048576` (1MB size calculated into bytes). However, created file is a bit larger - it has 1048630 bytes. I suppose it's because of a bitmap header file, but when I try to substract the header size from general size:

`img = Image.new('RGB', (1, (size-54)//4), "black")`

the size of the file generated is 1048576 - with 2 bytes out of nowhere.

How can I properly calculate what size to provide when creating BMP files? The content of such file can be random, doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want your file to be resized to 1048574 bytes if it exceeds this value:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
from stat import ST_SIZE

############## Your code below ##################

size = 1*1024*1024
img = Image.new('RGB', (1, (size)//4), "black")
pixels = img.load()
for i in range(img.size[0]):
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        pixels[i,j] = (i, j, 1)
img.save("image.bmp")

############# Your code above ##################

image_statistics = os.stat("image.bmp")
print("Initial image size: ", image_statistics[ST_SIZE])

difference = image_statistics[ST_SIZE] - size

if difference > 0:
    os.remove("image.bmp") #Delete first attempt.
    img = Image.new('RGB', (1, (size - difference)//4), "black") #Regenerate
    pixels = img.load() # Note: this segment is the same as the initial code.
    for i in range(img.size[0]):
        for j in range(img.size[1]):
            pixels[i,j] = (i, j, 1)
    img.save("image.bmp") #File saved with new size.

    image_statistics = os.stat("image.bmp")




print("New image size: ", image_statistics[ST_SIZE])
```

OUTPUT:

Initial image size:  1048630

New image size:  1048574

Comment: Is there really a need to create a file that is then removed? Can't it be done in just few lines or right from the start without creating-deleting-creating scenario at all?

Comment: This was something that I pondered for a little bit and the only way (I can think of) to be certain that it doesn't exceed a certain amount of memory is to check its actual memory after the file is created. However, you could change your initial code to subtract 56 bytes instead of 54, and then include the image_statistics check from my code and only do the image removal & regeneration if the image doesn't meet your requirements after subtracting 56 bytes. The frequency that this image regeneration would actually occur at this point would be much less than in the code I originally provided.